# Invoking big Data to a chart object in C#, WinForms

Tags: c#, performance, timer, invoke

I'm currently writing a program in C#.
I want to save much data (more than 200,000 times a double value) to a .csv file. This means that I have to sepparate all the values using a semicolon ";".

This is not the problem, but when I want to open the file again and read the data, the values should be drawn into a chart.

I'm reading the .csv file line by line, because reading all the data first would cause a memory overflow exception. I want to do this on a sepparate thread, so the form won't be blocked. Then I would also have to invoke the chart.

Now invoking controls many times takes a lot of time. I found similar problems on the internet where timers were used to solve the problem. I have already used timers instead of invoking progressbars, but in case, I don't know how to use this timer.

Is a timer possible here? How can I implement it? Is there a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear but there is at least one piece of information that will answer two parts of your question within it:

> I want to do this on a separate[sic] thread, so the form won't be blocked.

...

> Is there a different solution?

Using the task parallel library you can definitely keep the UI thread from blocking without needing to burden yourself with thread management.

This also allows you to display the steps needed to perform these tasks as "steps" in your progress bars.  You can then enumerate the steps and show a real progress bar instead of one that guesses.

```
protected void LoadData_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Execute a task without blocking the calling method
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoadDataAsync(); });

    // method finishes, does not block on the task
}

private async void LoadDataAsync()
{
    // Await the load and use the remainder of this method as callback
    UpdateProgressBar();

    int position = 0;
    int take = Constants.PreferredFetchQuantity;
    int total = MoreThan200xDoubleValue;

    while (CheckCancellationToken == false && position <= total)
    {
        var Data = await Task.Run(FetchDataRowsSlowly(position, take));

        // the remainder is a nice readable callback

        position += take;
        UpdateProgressBar(position);
        foreach(var row in Data) SomeGridOrSomething.Add(row);

        // ...
    }
}

private Task<DataTable> FetchDataRowsSlowly(int start, int count)
{
    var db = WhateverDbContextOrWebAPICallOrWhatever();

    // return datatable, the framework will handle the Task<>
    return db.GiantTable.Skip(start).Take(count).ToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: This would mean, I could insert Values to my chart without the needing of invoking and without blocking the main thread, doesn't it?

Comment: But the point is, that I can't fetch the data at once, like you suggested it with var Data = await Task.Run(FetchDataRowsSlowly()); and then add an item to the data grid for each of them. The Data I want to read is so much, that it would cause an Memory overflow. It has to be read line by line and after each line, the item in the grid has to be added.

Comment: Are you also suggesting that you need to paginate the result grid?  I still don't see anything about that in the actual question.  If you need to paginate the grid I think you'll find ample space to do that in the callback portion of the loading method.